# Rechargeable Bicycle Light Storage

Tags: lighting

For an expensive rechargeable bicycle light that is bright enough for daytime use, does it detract from charged state if left in a hot garage in the summer?  In other words is it better to bring in the house, especially if you customarily charge them in the house.

Comment: In general, you should not store batteries of any sort in a hot place for long periods of time, if it can be avoided.  (Automotive batteries are designed to be in hot places and are not a sensitive in this regard.)

Comment: In summer I tend to take my bike lights off and store them inside.  All batteries dislike being hot, so reducing temperature would be wise.

Comment: Battery life is best at room temperature, for either type, rechargeable or non-rechargeable.

Answer (score 5):

While this is more a question of battery science in general, it should be stressed that most batteries don't like heat and should be stored accordingly.

Also worth mentioning that all batteries lose some charge over time, even when disconnected and properly stored. The rate of self-discharge depends on the battery type and since you mentioned the equipment being expensive, I'd bet on it having a li-ion battery. Frequently charging them to full is a bad idea because they will suffer damage if kept at full charge for long, plus they self-discharge rather slowly. Aim for 70% charge every few months instead.